# cant get past the try or install screen

Tags: boot, system-installation

I get to the `try or install` screen then all goes black. Here are some images hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I dont know if I took the right pics but hope this helps.

I am using an hp touchsmart notebook pc

- 4gb ram
- 500gb hd
- 64bit win 8
- amd a6-5200 with radeon hd graphics.

I am also trying to install from a cd 13.10. I got the same results with 12.04.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps if not done already. In the bios menu:

- Turn off secure boot
- Choose manual as the preferred option instead of UEFI in the firmware option